# pandas dataframe how to replace None values in a column with list values or remove none values or pd.np.nan

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {
'list_id' : [[50, None],[20, 68],[10, 7],[73, 4, 26, 3],[50, None],[68, 20, 61, 62],[68, None]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print (df)
```

I tried the below steps,

expected Output

```
    data = {
'list_id' : [[50],[20, 68],[10, 7],[73, 4, 26, 3],[50],[68, 20, 61, 62],[68]]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print (df)
            list_id
0              [50]
1          [20, 68]
2           [10, 7]
3    [73, 4, 26, 3]
4              [50]
5  [68, 20, 61, 62]
6              [68]



 df[['list_id']] = df['list_id'].apply(lambda el: [  f'' if x is None else x for x in el])
 df[['list_id']] = df['list_id'].apply(lambda el: [  f'' if x is None for x in el])
```

Need to replace None values in column with list elements, either as an empty '' string or None being removed, not sure about np.nan..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For remove `None` or `NaN`s values use [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) in list comprehension:

```
df['list_id'] = df['list_id'].apply(lambda el: [x for x in el if pd.notna(x)])
print (df)
            list_id
0              [50]
1          [20, 68]
2           [10, 7]
3    [73, 4, 26, 3]
4              [50]
5  [68, 20, 61, 62]
6              [68]
```

For remove only `None`s compare by `None` with `not`:

```
df['list_id'] = df['list_id'].apply(lambda el: [x for x in el if x is not None])
```